# Does `gitk` have an option to automatically refresh its view (every 2 seconds, for example)

Tags: git, gitk

`gitk` supports F5 and Shift+F5 bindings to refresh its view. Is there any way to have it do that automatically?

For example, something similar to the [`refresh-interval` option](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man5/tigrc.5.html#:%7E:text=refresh%2Dinterval.-,refresh%2Dinterval,-(int)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Interval%20in) in `tig` would work for me.